# How to move an object back based on its rotation and bounds in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions, bounds

Alright, so I have an object and it also has a bounds. I also have an `anchorPoint`, if you will, which is where the object is positioned and I have a `boundary` Vector3 position that I don't want the object to pass.

EDIT:

I will clarify my example in the following scenario:

Alright, lets take a rectangular prism since it is a perfect example. Obviously, when you are looking at it long ways it won't be as close to you if you rotate it 90 degrees on the y to where you are looking at the end of the object. Even though the object didn't change positions and is essentially in the same position, just rotated. I want to check if during rotation did the object pass a certain point called `boundary`. If it is past the point then I want to move the object forward in its z-direction so that the end of the object intersects the `boundary` position.

Assume that the object's initial position stays the same in the image below.

[image: Example Rotation Image]

END EDIT

The problem comes into play when I want to rotate the object. How do I detect if part of the object has moved in front of this boundary position; that is not to say that the center of the object has passed this position but that part of the object has. I figured the best way to do this would be using bounds but, I'm not quite sure how to incorporate the rotation in with the bounds.

I haven't really had any luck with anything I have written so far. Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say `boundary`, what exactly do you mean? A `Vector3` position is just that, a point in space. Are you trying to determine if your object intersects some vector originating from `boundary` (e.g. with a direction of `boundary` - `origin`)? Or are you imagining a more physically-based boundary, e.g. a wall/plane/sphere? Maybe any point of the object extends more than n-units from some origin point?

Comment: It's just a position in space, but you can think of it as like a wall that I don't want it to pass but instead, moves the object backwards if it rotates past the point. The object position and boundary position are on the same plane. Which is why I just called it a Vector3.

Comment: You need more than just a point to define a boundary.  In your picture example, your unrotated cube is already straddling the boundary if that point marks a right-to-left boundary (instead of up-to-down).  So you need a point and a direction (which basically defines a plane).

Comment: Okay so then I can make it a plane, what next @avariant?

Comment: @Dtb49, I've added an answer with more description

Comment: @avariant I am testing out your answer and working through it. I'd call myself a decent programmer but, I am terrible at vector math haha

Comment: Understanding the basics of vector math is one of the most useful skills you can acquire.  It's one of those things you think in school "when will I ever use this", but I use it nearly every day! :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the simplest case, where you have a rectangular, axis aligned bounding box, then you have 8 points that make up your bounding box (the 8 corners).

The first check you want to make is to see if your anchor point is on the "wrong" side of your boundary plane.  This is a simple vector dot product check.

```
Vector3 anchorDir = anchorPoint - boundaryPoint;
bool wrongSide = Vector3.Dot(anchorDir, boundaryDir) <= 0;
```

As long as your anchor point is on the right side of the boundary, you can move on to check each of the 8 bounding box points in the exact same way.  However, you will need to make sure that your bounding points and your boundaryPoint are in the same coordinate system (world vs local) (this actually applies to your anchorPoint too).  You could translate all the points to World space using Transform.TransformPoint (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html) but it would be more efficient to translate the boundaryPoint to your bounding box's local coordinate system using InverseTransformPoint (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.InverseTransformPoint.html).

```
Transform boundingBox = ...
Vector3 localBoundaryPoint = boundingBox.InverseTransformPoint(worldBoundaryPoint);
Vector3 localBoundaryDir = boundingBox.InverseTransformDirection(boundaryDirection);
foreach(Vector3 pt in boundingBoxPoints)
{
    Vector3 pointDir = pt- localBoundaryPoint;
    bool ptWrongSide = Vector3.Dot(pointDir , localBoundaryDir ) <= 0;
    //How you handle that is up to you (return false, set a local flag and break, whatever)
}
```

**EDIT**:
If you want to know how *far* you are past the boundary so that you can shift your box back, you will need to handle that a little differently.  You will have to check all the points and not just return when you find the first violator because you can't be sure which one is furthest.

```
float maxDistance = 0;
foreach(Vector3 pt in boundingBoxPoints)
{
    Vector3 pointDir = pt- localBoundaryPoint;
    //note the negative sign
    float distance = -Vector3.Dot(pointDir, localBoundaryDir );
    if (distance > maxDistance) maxDistance = distance;
}
if (maxDistance> 0)
{
    //Shift your object by maxDistance amount along the localBoundaryDir;
}
```

Note that for your Dot Product to return the correct distance, localBoundaryDir needs to be a unit vector.

**EDIT 2**
Easier to describe the Boundary Point issue here than in the comments.

Your question doesn't explain how you define a Boundary Point, but let's assume that it's just a GameObject.  You can implement a script on it but technically you don't even need that.

```
GameObject boundaryObject = ...
Vector3 boundaryPoint = boundaryObject.transform.position;
Vector3 boundaryDir = boundaryObject.transform.forward;
```

`transform.forward` always points along the z-axis, the blue arrow.  So if, in the Unity editor you are constructing your scene, the blue arrow points along your plane's normal.  Your "boundary line" extends to the right and left (x axis, red arrow) and up and down (y axis, green arrow).

Comment: near the top, what is the boundaryDir?

Comment: Instead of defining your boundary as a single point, it needs to be a "plane". A plane is always defined as a point and a direction (usually called the "normal").  So in addition to a Vector3 for the position of your point, you need a Vector3 direction that defines the normal of your plane.  In your picture example, this would be a vector pointing up toward the top of the screen like the arrow you have drawn in the image.

Comment: Hmm, so do I have to create an actual plane object or can I determine this direction another way?

Comment: Not necessarily.  There is a Plane type defined in Unity3d and you can use it in a script, but you can also just define a Vector3 position and a Vector3 direction.